# PowerShell Command to Set Logging on IIS 10

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, iis-10

On Windows Server 2016/IIS 10, I can do the following in the IIS Manager GUI with the Log File Format set to W3C:

*[Web Server Name] → Logging → Select Fields → W3C Logging Fields (Standard Fields) → Check or uncheck the boxes next to Standard Fields* like "User Name (cs-username)"

I would really like to be able to check or uncheck fields like cs-username from a PowerShell script. To that end, I'm trying to discover the path to these standard fields, so I can then set them:

```
Import-Module IISAdministration

$prop = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" -Filter /system.applicationHost/sites/sitedefaults" -Recurse
```

When I run this PowerShell script, it asks me to "Supply values for the following parameters: Name[0].

I think it's a bit funny that it's asking me for a name when I'm trying to discover the next path element or name. If I type in something like cs-username, it comes back with nothing, suggesting I'm in the wrong directory (assuming recurse is actually looking around).

Any thoughts?

Comment: This looks more like an infrastructure management question than a programming question, so [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) might be a better place for it.

Comment: If I run the following PowerShell script, I can set the values I want to set, but at the Default Web Site level:

Import-Module IISAdministration
$siteName = "Default Web Site"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='$siteName']" -Name logFile.logExtFileFlags -Value "Date,Time,ClientIP,UserName,ComputerName,ServerIP,ServerPort,Method,UriStem,TimeTaken,UserAgent"
Start-Website -Name "$siteName"

Comment: If I try to just change the siteName to localhost or the machine name, I get an error that localhost is not found at path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'. That makes sense to me because paths are at the application level, for for the entire site:

Again, my question is how to programatically discover how to set these values for the entire server, not just the Default Web Site.

Comment: I did look under server fault, but did not find anything remotely close to answering my question. Another problem is that many examples on the web are based on the WebAdministration module in PowerShell. I'm on Windows Server 2016, and really want to use the new IISAdministration module that replaces WebAdministration.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me for IIS 10:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty `
    -filter "/*/*/site/logfile" `
    -name "logExtFileFlags" `
    -value "Date, Time, ClientIp, etc.."
```

of course replacing "etc.." with all the desired fields.